# postgresql.conf contains errors

Tags: postgresql, change-data-capture

I am trying to implement Kafka Connect service with Debezium Postgres Connector. Make changes for 'postgresql.conf' file such as:

- wal_level='logical'
- max_wal_senders='1'
- max_replication_slots='1'
- shared_preload_libraries='decoderbufs,wal2json'

After stopping and starting the Postgres service. The Postgres service failed to start. And unable to access 'psql'.

```
[postgres@supervm data]$ psql
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
[postgres@supervm data]$
```

Check the Postgres log:

```
2022-02-23 01:34:52.719 +08 [13458] LOG:  configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/14/data/postgresql.conf" contains errors; unaffected changes were applied    
2022-02-23 01:59:08.899 +08 [13458] LOG:  received fast shutdown request     
2022-02-23 01:59:08.939 +08 [13458] LOG:  aborting any active transactions   
2022-02-23 01:59:09.142 +08 [13458] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 13467) exited with exit code 1
2022-02-23 01:59:09.161 +08 [13462] LOG:  shutting down
2022-02-23 01:59:09.476 +08 [13458] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

How I can resolve this matter. Been web searching but there are not many on this error.

I am a newbie to change data capture using Debezium. Any help is really valuable to me.

The content of postgresql.conf:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# FILE LOCATIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# The default values of these variables are driven from the -D command-line
# option or PGDATA environment variable, represented here as ConfigDir.

#data_directory = 'ConfigDir'           # use data in another directory
                                        # (change requires restart)
#hba_file = 'ConfigDir/pg_hba.conf'     # host-based authentication file
                                        # (change requires restart)
#ident_file = 'ConfigDir/pg_ident.conf' # ident configuration file
                                        # (change requires restart)

# If external_pid_file is not explicitly set, no extra PID file is written.
#external_pid_file = ''                 # write an extra PID file
                                        # (change requires restart)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

#listen_addresses = 'localhost'         # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
#port = 5432                            # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql, /tmp'  # comma-separated list of directories
                                        # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''                 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777         # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off                          # advertise server via Bonjour
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''                      # defaults to the computer name
                                        # (change requires restart)

# - TCP settings -
# see "man tcp" for details

#tcp_keepalives_idle = 0                # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_interval = 0            # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_count = 0               # TCP_KEEPCNT;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_user_timeout = 0                   # TCP_USER_TIMEOUT, in milliseconds;
                                        # 0 selects the system default

#client_connection_check_interval = 0   # time between checks for client
                                        # disconnection while running queries;
                                        # 0 for never

# - Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min          # 1s-600s
#password_encryption = scram-sha-256    # scram-sha-256 or md5
#db_user_namespace = off

# GSSAPI using Kerberos
#krb_server_keyfile = 'FILE:${sysconfdir}/krb5.keytab'
#krb_caseins_users = off

# - SSL -

#ssl = off
#ssl_ca_file = ''
#ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
#ssl_crl_file = ''
#ssl_crl_dir = ''
#ssl_key_file = 'server.key'
#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'
#ssl_min_protocol_version = 'TLSv1.2'
#ssl_max_protocol_version = ''
#ssl_dh_params_file = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command_supports_reload = off


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RESOURCE USAGE (except WAL)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Memory -

shared_buffers = 128MB                  # min 128kB
                                        # (change requires restart)
#huge_pages = try                       # on, off, or try
                                        # (change requires restart)
#huge_page_size = 0                     # zero for system default
                                        # (change requires restart)
#temp_buffers = 8MB                     # min 800kB
#max_prepared_transactions = 0          # zero disables the feature
                                        # (change requires restart)
# Caution: it is not advisable to set max_prepared_transactions nonzero unless
# you actively intend to use prepared transactions.
#work_mem = 4MB                         # min 64kB
#hash_mem_multiplier = 1.0              # 1-1000.0 multiplier on hash table work_mem
#maintenance_work_mem = 64MB            # min 1MB
#autovacuum_work_mem = -1               # min 1MB, or -1 to use maintenance_work_mem
#logical_decoding_work_mem = 64MB       # min 64kB
#max_stack_depth = 2MB                  # min 100kB
#shared_memory_type = mmap              # the default is the first option
                                        # supported by the operating system:
                                        #   mmap
                                        #   sysv
                                        #   windows
                                        # (change requires restart)
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix      # the default is the first option
                                        # supported by the operating system:
                                        #   posix
                                        #   sysv
                                        #   windows
                                        #   mmap
                                        # (change requires restart)
#min_dynamic_shared_memory = 0MB        # (change requires restart)

# - Disk -

#temp_file_limit = -1                   # limits per-process temp file space
                                        # in kilobytes, or -1 for no limit

# - Kernel Resources -

#max_files_per_process = 1000           # min 64
                                        # (change requires restart)

# - Cost-Based Vacuum Delay -

#vacuum_cost_delay = 0                  # 0-100 milliseconds (0 disables)
#vacuum_cost_page_hit = 1               # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_page_miss = 2              # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_page_dirty = 20            # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_limit = 200                # 1-10000 credits

# - Background Writer -

#bgwriter_delay = 200ms                 # 10-10000ms between rounds
#bgwriter_lru_maxpages = 100            # max buffers written/round, 0 disables
#bgwriter_lru_multiplier = 2.0          # 0-10.0 multiplier on buffers scanned/round
#bgwriter_flush_after = 512kB           # measured in pages, 0 disables

# - Asynchronous Behavior -

#backend_flush_after = 0                # measured in pages, 0 disables
#effective_io_concurrency = 1           # 1-1000; 0 disables prefetching
#maintenance_io_concurrency = 10        # 1-1000; 0 disables prefetching
#max_worker_processes = 8               # (change requires restart)
#max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2    # taken from max_parallel_workers
#max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 2   # taken from max_parallel_workers
#max_parallel_workers = 8               # maximum number of max_worker_processes that
                                        # can be used in parallel operations
#parallel_leader_participation = on
#old_snapshot_threshold = -1            # 1min-60d; -1 disables; 0 is immediate
                                        # (change requires restart)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WRITE-AHEAD LOG
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Settings -

wal_level = logical                     # minimal, replica, or logical
                                        # (change requires restart)
#fsync = on                             # flush data to disk for crash safety
                                        # (turning this off can cause
                                        # unrecoverable data corruption)
#synchronous_commit = on                # synchronization level;
                                        # off, local, remote_write, remote_apply, or on
#wal_sync_method = fsync                # the default is the first option
                                        # supported by the operating system:
                                        #   open_datasync
                                        #   fdatasync (default on Linux and FreeBSD)
                                        #   fsync
                                        #   fsync_writethrough
                                        #   open_sync
#full_page_writes = on                  # recover from partial page writes
#wal_log_hints = off                    # also do full page writes of non-critical updates
                                        # (change requires restart)
#wal_compression = off                  # enable compression of full-page writes
#wal_init_zero = on                     # zero-fill new WAL files
#wal_recycle = on                       # recycle WAL files
#wal_buffers = -1                       # min 32kB, -1 sets based on shared_buffers
                                        # (change requires restart)
#wal_writer_delay = 200ms               # 1-10000 milliseconds
#wal_writer_flush_after = 1MB           # measured in pages, 0 disables
#wal_skip_threshold = 2MB

#commit_delay = 0                       # range 0-100000, in microseconds
#commit_siblings = 5                    # range 1-1000

# - Checkpoints -

#checkpoint_timeout = 5min              # range 30s-1d
#checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9     # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0
#checkpoint_flush_after = 256kB         # measured in pages, 0 disables
#checkpoint_warning = 30s               # 0 disables
max_wal_size = 1GB
min_wal_size = 80MB

# - Archiving -

#archive_mode = off             # enables archiving; off, on, or always
                                # (change requires restart)
#archive_command = ''           # command to use to archive a logfile segment
                                # placeholders: %p = path of file to archive
                                #               %f = file name only
                                # e.g. 'test ! -f /mnt/server/archivedir/%f && cp %p /mnt/server/archivedir/%f'
#archive_timeout = 0            # force a logfile segment switch after this
                                # number of seconds; 0 disables

# - Archive Recovery -

# These are only used in recovery mode.

#restore_command = ''           # command to use to restore an archived logfile segment
                                # placeholders: %p = path of file to restore
                                #               %f = file name only
                                # e.g. 'cp /mnt/server/archivedir/%f %p'
#archive_cleanup_command = ''   # command to execute at every restartpoint
#recovery_end_command = ''      # command to execute at completion of recovery

# - Recovery Target -

# Set these only when performing a targeted recovery.

#recovery_target = ''           # 'immediate' to end recovery as soon as a
                                # consistent state is reached
                                # (change requires restart)
#recovery_target_name = ''      # the named restore point to which recovery will proceed
                                # (change requires restart)
#recovery_target_time = ''      # the time stamp up to which recovery will proceed
                                # (change requires restart)
#recovery_target_xid = ''       # the transaction ID up to which recovery will proceed
                                # (change requires restart)
#recovery_target_lsn = ''       # the WAL LSN up to which recovery will proceed
                                # (change requires restart)
#recovery_target_inclusive = on # Specifies whether to stop:
                                # just after the specified recovery target (on)
                                # just before the recovery target (off)
                                # (change requires restart)
#recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'    # 'current', 'latest', or timeline ID
                                # (change requires restart)
#recovery_target_action = 'pause'       # 'pause', 'promote', 'shutdown'
                                # (change requires restart)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REPLICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Sending Servers -

# Set these on the primary and on any standby that will send replication data.

max_wal_senders = 1             # max number of walsender processes
                                # (change requires restart)
max_replication_slots = 1       # max number of replication slots
                                # (change requires restart)
#wal_keep_size = 0              # in megabytes; 0 disables
#max_slot_wal_keep_size = -1    # in megabytes; -1 disables
#wal_sender_timeout = 60s       # in milliseconds; 0 disables
#track_commit_timestamp = off   # collect timestamp of transaction commit
                                # (change requires restart)

# - Primary Server -

# These settings are ignored on a standby server.

#synchronous_standby_names = '' # standby servers that provide sync rep
                                # method to choose sync standbys, number of sync standbys,
                                # and comma-separated list of application_name
                                # from standby(s); '*' = all
#vacuum_defer_cleanup_age = 0   # number of xacts by which cleanup is delayed

# - Standby Servers -

# These settings are ignored on a primary server.

#primary_conninfo = ''                  # connection string to sending server
#primary_slot_name = ''                 # replication slot on sending server
#promote_trigger_file = ''              # file name whose presence ends recovery
#hot_standby = on                       # "off" disallows queries during recovery
                                        # (change requires restart)
#max_standby_archive_delay = 30s        # max delay before canceling queries
                                        # when reading WAL from archive;
                                        # -1 allows indefinite delay
#max_standby_streaming_delay = 30s      # max delay before canceling queries
                                        # when reading streaming WAL;
                                        # -1 allows indefinite delay
#wal_receiver_create_temp_slot = off    # create temp slot if primary_slot_name
                                        # is not set
#wal_receiver_status_interval = 10s     # send replies at least this often
                                        # 0 disables
#hot_standby_feedback = off             # send info from standby to prevent
                                        # query conflicts
#wal_receiver_timeout = 60s             # time that receiver waits for
                                        # communication from primary
                                        # in milliseconds; 0 disables
#wal_retrieve_retry_interval = 5s       # time to wait before retrying to
                                        # retrieve WAL after a failed attempt
#recovery_min_apply_delay = 0           # minimum delay for applying changes during recovery

# - Subscribers -

# These settings are ignored on a publisher.

#max_logical_replication_workers = 4    # taken from max_worker_processes
                                        # (change requires restart)
#max_sync_workers_per_subscription = 2  # taken from max_logical_replication_workers




#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CLIENT CONNECTION DEFAULTS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Statement Behavior -

#client_min_messages = notice           # values in order of decreasing detail:
                                        #   debug5
                                        #   debug4
                                        #   debug3
                                        #   debug2
                                        #   debug1
                                        #   log
                                        #   notice
                                        #   warning
                                        #   error
#search_path = '"$user", public'        # schema names
#row_security = on
#default_table_access_method = 'heap'
#default_tablespace = ''                # a tablespace name, '' uses the default
#default_toast_compression = 'pglz'     # 'pglz' or 'lz4'
#temp_tablespaces = ''                  # a list of tablespace names, '' uses
                                        # only default tablespace
#check_function_bodies = on
#default_transaction_isolation = 'read committed'
#default_transaction_read_only = off
#default_transaction_deferrable = off
#session_replication_role = 'origin'
#statement_timeout = 0                  # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
#lock_timeout = 0                       # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
#idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0        # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
#idle_session_timeout = 0               # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
#vacuum_freeze_table_age = 150000000
#vacuum_freeze_min_age = 50000000
#vacuum_failsafe_age = 1600000000
#vacuum_multixact_freeze_table_age = 150000000
#vacuum_multixact_freeze_min_age = 5000000
#vacuum_multixact_failsafe_age = 1600000000
#bytea_output = 'hex'                   # hex, escape
#xmlbinary = 'base64'
#xmloption = 'content'
#gin_pending_list_limit = 4MB

# - Locale and Formatting -

datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
#intervalstyle = 'postgres'
timezone = 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'
#timezone_abbreviations = 'Default'     # Select the set of available time zone
                                        # abbreviations.  Currently, there are
                                        #   Default
                                        #   Australia (historical usage)
                                        #   India
                                        # You can create your own file in
                                        # share/timezonesets/.
#extra_float_digits = 1                 # min -15, max 3; any value >0 actually
                                        # selects precise output mode
#client_encoding = sql_ascii            # actually, defaults to database
                                        # encoding

# These settings are initialized by initdb, but they can be changed.
lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'                     # locale for system error message
                                        # strings
lc_monetary = 'en_US.UTF-8'                     # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'en_US.UTF-8'                      # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'en_US.UTF-8'                         # locale for time formatting

# default configuration for text search
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'

# - Shared Library Preloading -

#local_preload_libraries = ''
#session_preload_libraries = ''
shared_preload_libraries = 'decoderbufs,wal2json'       # (change requires restart)
#jit_provider = 'llvmjit'               # JIT library to use

# - Other Defaults -

#dynamic_library_path = '$libdir'
#gin_fuzzy_search_limit = 0
```

Comment: You're going to need to show your full Postgres config file. As the error says, it has some issue

Comment: Can't share the full Postgres config file since has word limits. But I think based on the logs the main issue is 'background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 13467) exited with exit code 1'

Comment: I would say you need to read [Replication settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html). `max_wal_senders` "...The default is 10..." and `max_replication_slots` "...The default is 10... Setting it to a lower value than the number of currently existing replication slots will prevent the server from starting. ..."

Comment: Please show the PostgreSQL error messages when you reload or restart.

Comment: "logical replication launcher" (PID 13467) exited with exit code 1". That message is normal whenever postgresql shuts down, it is unimportant here.  But there should be a newer log file and/or entries describing why the start up failed.

Comment: I'm getting the same error as you. Can you post the LOG just above "contains error"?

mine says "parameter "shared_preload_libraries" cannot be changed without restarting the server" and I wonder if that's related

Answer (score 0):

I saw this `contains errors; unaffected changes` in the `/var/log` file, and found that the actual errors were in the systemd journal. Try `journalctl -u postgresql@13-main` (adjust for whatever version you're running.

Once you have the actual error log in hand, you should be able to address your configuration issue.  In my case, I was binding to an invalid address:

```
# journalctl -u postgresql@13-main
...
Oct 21 ...: Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/13/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.co>
Oct 21 ...: 2022-10-21 18:47:20 UTC LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.8 (Ubuntu 13.8-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, 64-bit
Oct 21 ...: 2022-10-21 18:47:20 UTC LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "172.17.0.1": Cannot assign requested address
Oct 21 ...: 2022-10-21 18:47:20 UTC HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
Oct 21 ...: 2022-10-21 18:47:20 UTC WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "172.17.0.1"
Oct 21 ...: 2022-10-21 18:47:20 UTC FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
Oct 21 ...: 2022-10-21 18:47:20 UTC LOG:  database system is shut down
Oct 21 ...: pg_ctl: could not start server
```